# How do I reinstall elementary OS and leave other operating systems undisturbed?

Tags: release-freya, system-installation

I would like to reinstall elementary OS 0.3.1 Freya on my laptop. My system is currently in a dual boot with Linux Mint. How can I reinstall elementary OS and leave Linux Mint undisturbed? I also don't want to mess up GRUB.

I currently have 200 GB allocated to elementary OS, and the rest allocated to Linux Mint. I want to reinstall elementary OS only in this space.

Thanks!